# How do I make the django admin site rely on my custom Django Rest Framework Token Authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-admin, django-rest-auth

Throughout development of my application, the authentication has worked great. Using DRF I overrode DRF's TokenAuthentication to provide an expiring token, and then overrode ObtainAuthToken to create the authentication post request view.

Now I'm trying to launch the application into production with DEBUG=False. The application seems to be running fine, but the django admin site will not let me log in to my super user (yes I created it with createsuperuser and have verified it exists in the database). The error I get back is:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
```

This confused me because I'm using Token authentication and not Sessions. In my settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'custom_auth.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication'
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

I believe the django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware was put in there by default when I created the application, and I assume this is why it is throwing the csrf error. However, when I inspect the request body when logging in, it is, in fact, including a csrf token. Request payload (changed values):

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=iAifasdfOnxkiMeRRtByt3dZHar6zvDNDrrWasdfC0LBBuI8NxrnWwuM1asdf&username=user%40example.com&password=password&next=%2Fadmin%2F
```

Also, after some reading it seems like the django admin site ignores custom authentication classes and just uses sessions still anyway. If so, how do I change this?

Second, there's a chance the error goes away if I remove the csrf middleware. However, I'm hesitant to do so since I'm not sure I fully understand the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add SessionAuthentication in DRF settings solve your problem:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'custom_auth.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

for more information read [DRF docs about session authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)

Comment: There's a good chance this could work, but I was hoping to use the expiring token authentication I created instead of the django session authentication

Comment: I think you need to write authentication backend for Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)  because by default Django uses Session authentication, which depends on cookies on the client to store the user session information once the user is logged in.